# Switching photo position via click on thumbnail with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to put a photo view/slideshow on my webpage and I am not getting the results I am looking for. I have created a Fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/RfKh4/) to show you what I am trying to do. What I want it to do is when you click a thumbnail it switches the thumbnail into the main photo spot and the main photo into the thumbnail spot. It works at first but after you start clicking the other thumbnails it starts not switching the correct photo into the main slot. Also if you reclick the thumbnail you just clicked it does nothing. Here is my jquery code but take a look at my fiddle and you will be able to see what I am trying to do.

```
$('.thumb1').click(function() {
    $('.thumb1, .main').fadeIn().toggleClass('thumb1 main');
});

$('.thumb2').click(function() {
    $('.thumb2, .main').fadeIn().toggleClass('thumb2 main');
});

$('.thumb3').click(function() {
    $('.thumb3, .main').fadeIn().toggleClass('thumb3 main');
});

$('.thumb4').click(function() {
    $('.thumb4, .main').fadeIn().toggleClass('thumb4 main');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed your classes similarly to how [Joao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2854344/joao) did, but my JavaScript is a little different

```
$('.thumb').click(function () {
    var newHTML = this.innerHTML;
    this.innerHTML = $('.main')[0].innerHTML
    $('.main').html(newHTML);
});
```

Instead of just changing the `src`, you will also keep all other attributes of the images, such as the `alt` attribute, which you should add to your images for accessibility purposes.

I didn't implement the idea of not having clicking the same one do nothing, because then if they want to look at the image they just looked at they can't.

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/RfKh4/6/**

Comment: Hey Thanks, both of your answers work great. I didnt make that clear but my code did nothing when I clicked the same image and I wanted it to do what both of your codes do.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking at your code, and I wouldn't recommend switching around classes between elements like that since it might throw out a couple of bugs like yours. I played around with your code and simplified a little bit:

```
$('.thumb').click(function () {
    var previousSrc = $('.main').children().attr('src');
    $('.main').children().attr('src', $(this).children().attr('src'));
    $(this).children().attr('src', previousSrc);
});
```

Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RfKh4/5/

Basically what I did was save the previous src attribute of the .main div image inside previousSrc and then I change the div's image to the one in the thumbnail. And finally change the thumbnail's image to the one that was on the .main div. Hope it helps you!

Comment: Your code works great but I am going with @howderek as his also includes changing the alt attribute that I have in my actual code being used.

Comment: Yes I also read his answer and you should go with his since it's a little better!